# How to create named mutex in Golang?

Tags: go

I am fairly new to Golang and trying to create a named mutex. I am trying to replicate:

```
    hMutex = CreateMutex( 
    NULL,                        // default security descriptor
    FALSE,                       // mutex not owned
    TEXT("NameOfMutexObject"));  // object name
```

The examples I see in sync don't appear to illustrate named mutexes.

Comment: The standard library mutex does not include naming. What kind of use case are you trying to replicate here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a named mutex using sync - is this what you are looking for?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var mutexMap sync.Map

func createMutex(name string) *sync.Mutex {
    mutex, ok := mutexMap.Load(name)
    if !ok {
        newMutex := &sync.Mutex{}
        mutex, _ = mutexMap.LoadOrStore(name, newMutex)
    }
    return mutex.(*sync.Mutex)
}

func main() {
    hMutex := createMutex("NameOfMutexObject")
    hMutex.Lock()
    fmt.Println("Locked Mutex: NameOfMutexObject")
    hMutex.Unlock()
    fmt.Println("Unlocked Mutex: NameOfMutexObject")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Named mutexes (in Windows) are really intended for use when sharing a mutex between/across processes and/or to simplify referencing the same mutex from different parts of the code in a single process (creating the mutex in one place and "opening" an existing mutex in other places).

A mutex in Go is more similar to a critical section in Windows (in concept at least, I cannot speak to the underlying implementation).

In Windows, named mutexes enable different processes to share mutexes by obtaining a reference to one, by its name.

To share a mutex in Go you either declare the mutex such that it is referencable where required or pass a reference to any functions that need it.

It follows that mutexes (in Go) cannot be shared between processes; if that's your use case then you will need to explore other cross-process synchronization mechanisms.  But if all you need is to synchronize threads in the same process, just use a mutex and don't worry about the fact that you can't git it a name. :)